# Java recursion with two variables

Tags: java, recursion

I've been trying to figure out how the stack of this recursive method will look like.

```
public class Apples {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
       q1(5);   
    }

    public static int q1 (int x) {
        if (x < 1) {
            System.out.println(x);
            return 1;
        }
        int a = 3 + q1(x / 2);
        int b = 2 * q1(x - 2) + 1;
        System.out.println(x + ";" + a + ";" + b);
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

But so far, I only think that the stack grows according to x/2:

```
x=0   returns 1;
x=1  a=4  b=3     returns 7;
x=2  a=10 b=3     returns 13;
x=5  a=16 b=9     returns 19;
```

This is obviously neither true nor complete. Please help me understand how does the stack build up.

Comment: Are you asking about the actual calling convention and how stack frames are made, or the vertical height of the recursion tree?

Comment: The actual calling convention

Comment: You should run this through a debugger, so you can see the output of each call to the method, and how many times you called the method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Theory**:

Each time, this function will recurse down the `q1(x/2)` path first, until it reaches the ending condition. Then, all pending `q1(x-2)` calls will be handled. Now this is where it gets tricky, at every `q1(x-2)` we first handle `q1(x/2)`. Thus, we are now back to the same spot as before, just one layer down, repeating until we handle all the `q1(x-2)` calls (in the last `q1(x/2)` layer).

One way to think of it is like a tree:

[image: 3 layers of the recursion tree. (c) The Brofessor]

> I only think that the stack grows according to x/2

You are right, if by the above you mean that this function recurses much faster in the `q1(x/2)` than in the `q1(x-2)` direction. Nonetheless, what you are saying implies it grows in *lg(n)* fashion (*lg(n)* is base 2).

However, we still need to analyze the other stack frames, so we set up the following recurrence relation:

*T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n-2) + c1*

Comment: The diagram just made things clear. I actually am new to recursion and I wasn't talking about the runtime of the algorithm. Thank You

Comment: That recursion will be *nasty*! Of course, you will notice that `x-2` dominates here, and not `x/2`, so it may not be stirctly logarithmic.

Comment: Ah, the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), I remember that...

Answer (score 4):

The stack for this recursive function will grow initially due to the repeated recursive calls made to compute the value of `a`; that is, we will keep calling `q1(x/2)` until `x/2 < 1`, in which case we have reached the base case of the recursion and can simply return 1.

Each time we return from one of the initial `q1(x/2)` calls, we then have to follow the `q1(x-2)` call that is made to compute `b`. That recursive call will also have a series of consecutive recursive calls for `a` (since `a` is computed first in your function), which follow the same rule; after each one returns, we make a recursive call for `b`, and this process repeats until we reach the base case in all of the branches of calls.

Here's how the stack would look. The order to read it in is to follow the vertical arrows first as far as you can, return, then follow the diagonal arrow. Repeat this process after following a diagonal arrow. When there are no arrows to follow, return.

By the way, stack frames for returned functions will be completely deallocated, and a new function call, if one is made, will take its place. You can see that at any given time, there are no more than 4 stack frames active. When the last topmost stack frame is finished, it is deallocated, and its spot is taken by the stack below and to the right. You return from that, and so on...

Hopefully this diagram helps clear it up.

```
                |                  |                  |
                |                  |                  |
                |                  |                  |
  +--------+    |                  |                  |
  | a =    |    |                  |                  |
  | b =    |    |                  |                  |
  +--------+    |                  |                  |
  | x = 0  |
  +--------+
  returns 1 

       ^             +--------+
       |             | a =    |
       |             | b =    |
       |             +--------+
       |          /  | x = -1 |
       |         /   +--------+
       |        /    returns 1
       |       /
  +--------+  /            
  | a = 4  | /             
  | b = 3  |/              
  +--------|               
  | x = 1  |               
  +--------+               
  returns 7                

       ^             +--------+
       |             | a =    |
       |             | b =    |
       |             +--------+
       |          /  | x = 0  |
       |         /   +--------+
       |        /    returns 1
       |       /
  +--------+  /           
  | a = 10 | /             
  | b = 3  |/              
  +--------+               
  | x = 2  |               
  +--------+               
  returns 13               

       ^             +--------+
       |             | a =    |
       |             | b =    |
       |             +--------+
       |             | x = 0  |
       |             +--------+
       |             returns 1
       |
       |                  ^             +--------+
       |                  |             | a =    |
       |                  |             | b =    |
       |                  |             +--------+
       |                  |          /  | x = -1 |
       |                  |         /   +--------+
       |                  |        /    returns 1
       |                  |       /
       |             +--------+  /
       |             | a = 4  | /
       |             | b = 3  |/
       |             +--------+
       |             | x = 1  |
       |             +--------+
       |             returns 7
       |                  
       |                  ^             +--------+
       |                  |             | a =    |
       |                  |             | b =    |
       |                  |             +--------+
       |                  |             | x = 0  |
       |                  |             +--------+
       |                  |             returns 1
       |                  |
       |                  |                  ^             +--------+
       |                  |                  |             | a =    |
       |                  |                  |             | b =    |
       |                  |                  |             +--------+
       |                  |                  |          /  | x = -1 |
       |                  |                  |         /   +--------+
       |                  |                  |        /    returns 1
       |                  |                  |       /
       |                  |             +--------+  /
       |                  |             | a = 4  | /
       |                  |             | b = 3  |/
       |                  |             +--------+
       |                  |          /  | x = 1  |
       |                  |         /   +--------+
       |                  |        /    returns 7               
       |                  |       /                    
       |                  |      /                     
       |             +--------+ /                      
       |             | a = 10 |/                       
       |             | b = 15 |                        
       |             +--------+                        
       |          /  | x = 3  |                        
       |         /   +--------+                        
       |        /    returns 25                        
       |       /                                       
  +--------+  /                                        
  | a = 16 | /                                         
  | b = 51 |/                                          
  +--------+    |                  |                  |
  | x = 5  |    |                  |                  |
  +--------+    |                  |                  |
  returns 67    |                  |                  |
                |                  |                  |
                |                  |                  |
                |                  |                  |
```

The Brofessor has a good theoretical approach going, but something he says is slightly inaccurate; when he says that `q1(x/2)` recurses faster than `q1(x-2)`, he means that the former will reach its base case quickly compared to the latter. Think about larger numbers than 5. For large values of `x`, `x/2` is much smaller than `x-2`. So, the `x-2` case ends up making many more recursive calls than the `x/2` case, so the `x-2` calls dominates the growth of the stack.

For instance, `q1(64)` will have 7 recursive calls for `q1(x/2)` (64/2, 32/2, ..., 1/2 = 0). But it will have so many more recursive calls for `q1(x-2)` (64-2, 62-2, 60-2, ..., 2-2 = 0).

In his drawing, something more realistic would be if the right subtree was larger, because that subtree will take a lot longer to bottom out. In fact, you can see this in my diagram. If you consider the vertical and diagonal arrows the branches of a tree, the subtree for the very first recursive call using `x/2` only has 5 nodes, while the subtree for the very first recursive call using `x-2` has 7 nodes. This will almost always be the case.

Answer (score 2):

To know actual calling conversion start with `q1(0), q1(1)...`

I can help you for `q1(2)`, then you can easily try for `q1(5)`.

```
x = -1, q1(-1) => 1 // "q1(-1) => 1" means q1 returns 1
x = 0, q1(0) => 1 // "q1(0) => 1" means q1 returns 1

x = 1, a = 3 + q1(0) = 3 + 1 = 4
       b = 2 * q1(-1) + 1 = 2*1 + 1 = 3
       q1(1) => 7

x = 2, a = 3 + q1(1) = 3 + 7 = 10
       b = 2 * q1(0) + 1 = 2*1 + 1 = 3
       q1(2) => 13

...
```

So you can print `q1(2)` and you will get output `13`. Debugging will help you for better understanding.